# Java Restful Response coming back with missing List name

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I have been trying to find an answer to my problem, however, so far I have been unsuccessful.  I am trying to do a POST operation:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@POST
@Path(value="/search")

{
  "firstName": "JOHN",
  "lastName": "SMITH"
}
```

The results:

```
{
  "members": [
    {
      "memberID": "1",
      "firstName": "JOHN",
      "lastName": "SMITH",
      "memberAddresses": {
        "memberAddresses": [
          {
            "memberAddressID": 74128225,
            "addr1": "123 MAIN ST",
          }
         ]
       }
```

WEB.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>CIS-Services</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <async-supported>false</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <resource-ref>
    <description />
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/CISDB_DS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
        /*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The results are correct, however I am getting a duplicate tags (memberAddresses) in the inner List.  Is there any way to just return the second memberAddresses tag?

Comment: Just did.  Thanks!

Comment: Contact the API person. If that is you, then `memberAddresses` should be a list itself, not an object containing a list

Comment: "*Is there any way to just return the second memberAddresses tag*" -- That's doubtful. What is wrong with extracting that value yourself?